# How do I add to a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've been going through a bootcamp, and I can't seem to figure out how to add to a function in Javascript, specifically when I've already placed my return value. For example, this function runs, but if someone said "okay, now if there is no one that matches the studying string, return a message that reads "No matches." Where do I add a new if statement saying "if (newArr.length = 0) {return "No matches.} Desperately needing help on this, and I've got an exam on JS functions tomorrow. Thought I had everything down, until this big ole curveball. Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

```js
let people = [{
    name: "Nick",
    studying: "JS",
    age: "33"
  },

  {
    name: "Joseph",
    studying: "JS",
    age: "137"
  },

  {
    name: "Jeff",
    studying: "education",
    age: "1897374"
  }
];

function returnArrOfNames(people, string) {
  let newArr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    if (people[i].studying === string) {
      newArr.push(people[i].name)
    }
  }
  return newArr
}

console.log(returnArrOfNames(people, "JS"));
```

Comment: if all you want to do is return a different value if the array is empty add that line before `return newArr`. The return will exit from the function

Comment: Have you tried placing that line in your code anywhere yet? Where do you think you would put it (even if you're just guessing)? PS: You need to use `===` or `==` in your if-statement, singular `=` is for assignment, not for comparison. Also, you need to make sure you close your string: `"No matches.` -- should be --> `"No matches."`

Answer (score 0):

Before you return `newArr` you can check it's length and if it's zero return "No matches".

```
let people = [{
    name: "Nick",
    studying: "JS",
    age: "33"
  },

  {
    name: "Joseph",
    studying: "JS",
    age: "137"
  },

  {
    name: "Jeff",
    studying: "education",
    age: "1897374"
  }
];

function returnArrOfNames(people, string) {
  let newArr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    if (people[i].studying === string) {
      newArr.push(people[i].name)
    }
  }

  if (newArr.length === 0) {
    return "No matches";
  }

  return newArr
}

console.log(returnArrOfNames(people, "JS"));
```

Comment: @ferrelnm looks like you have that code in your answer - you just need to place it before your original return. Although you should make sure whatever uses the result of `returnArrOfNames()` checks if the result is a string first.

Answer (score 0):

edit: I posted the same answer as someone else sorry.

You can just add that if statement outside the for loop. Like this:

```
let people = [
  {name : "Nick",
  studying : "JS",
  age : "33"},

  {name : "Joseph",
  studying : "JS",
  age : "137"},

  {name : "Jeff",
  studying : "education",
  age : "1897374"}
];

function returnArrOfNames(people, string) {
   let newArr = []
   for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
      if (people[i].studying === string) {
          newArr.push(people[i].name)
      }
   }
   if (newArr.length == 0){
       return console.log("no matches")
   }

   console.log(newArr);
   return newArr
}


returnArrOfNames(people, "JS")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `Array prototype's` `map` and `filter` method to get the result:

```js
let people = [{
    name: "Nick",
    studying: "JS",
    age: "33"
  },

  {
    name: "Joseph",
    studying: "JS",
    age: "137"
  },

  {
    name: "Jeff",
    studying: "education",
    age: "1897374"
  }
];


function returnArrOfNames(people = [], studying) {
  const NO_MATCHES = 'No Matches'
  const isEmpty = people.length === 0
  if (isEmpty) {
    return NO_MATCHES
  }
  
  const filterFn = i => i.studying === studying
  const filteredPeople = people.filter(filterFn)
  const isEmptyFilteredPeople = filteredPeople.length === 0;
  if(isEmptyFilteredPeople) return NO_MATCHES
  
  const mapFn = i => i.name
  const mappedPeople = filteredPeople.map(mapFn);
  return mappedPeople
}

console.log(returnArrOfNames(people, "JS"));
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 0):

the more simple is array.reduce method, and use a ternary condition for return

```js
const people = 
  [ { name: 'Nick',   studying: 'JS',        age: '33'      } 
  , { name: 'Joseph', studying: 'JS',        age: '137'     } 
  , { name: 'Jeff',   studying: 'education', age: '1897374' } 
  ] 
function returnArrOfNames(arr, study)
  {
  let newArr = arr.reduce((a,c)=>
      {
      if (c.studying===study) a.push(c.name)
      return a
      }, [])
  return  newArr.length ? newArr : 'no matches'
  }
console.log(' JS ? ->', returnArrOfNames(people, "JS") )  // Array [ "Nick", "Joseph" ]
console.log(' xx ? ->', returnArrOfNames(people, "xx") )  // "no matches"
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```